# Django how to use TinyIntegerField or SmallIntegerField for Primary Key?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'd like to create a table for less than 255 choices that should be presented to a user, and use an integer of 1 byte as the primary key. Something like in the following code, but preferably with a TinyIntegerField if it's possible to create one.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.SmallIntegerField(auto_increment=True, primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)

class Test(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

1. I'm assuming that there's no TinyInteger in Django because there
   isn't one in Postgres. Why isn't there tinyint in Postgres?
2. In the Django docs, the only auto-increment is an `AutoField`, how can auto-increment be applied to a `SmallIntegerField`?

Answer (score 6):

You say you want to *use an integer of 1 byte as the primary key*. I say, don't bother.

An integer is 4 bytes, and if there are less than 255 choices you are saving less than 765 (255*3) bytes.

For comparison, this line of code (including spaces):

```
    id = models.SmallIntegerField(auto_increment=True, primary_key=True)
```

in ASCII is 72 bytes long (74 if you count line endings). So if you have less than 72 options you've wasted more bytes in your code than you've saved in your database.

Your idea is premature optimisation at its worst, and will just introduce a possible area for bugs.

---

Since you insist on an answer...

Based on [this snippet for a `BigAutoField`](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1244/) and the [internals for a SmallIntegerField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py), this code should work:

```
class TinyAutoField(fields.AutoField):

    def db_type(self):
        return "smallint AUTO_INCREMENT"

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "SmallIntegerField"

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        try:
            return int(value)
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                _("This value must be a short integer."))
```

I won't do the math, except to say the storage of this code is far greater than the bytes you'll save in the database. Not to say of the time required to debug your custom `AutoField`.

Comment: It didn't work, you were right too many bugs and complications. I decided to use a smallintfield and hardcode the choices in the model, which is a better solution actually so a new db wouldn't require someone to go in and manually input the default choices every time.

Comment: The saving is not for the primary table, but in the foreign key table. Say you have 1 million fact type rows (PK), referencing each 8 dimension type columns (FK). Changing from int64 to int8 uses 12.5% of the original data (61MB vs 488MB).

Answer (score 3):

In django 3.0 there is a 2 byte [SmallAutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#smallautofield):

> Like an AutoField, but only allows values under a certain (database-dependent) limit. Values from 1 to 32767 are safe in all databases supported by Django.

```
id = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
```

[Postgresql's smallest number type is 2 bytes (small int)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html).
Although not as small as 1 byte, and least it halves the usage. Some say its not worth doing, what they havent thought about the saving on the FK table, where a reference maybe be repeated millions/billions of times, and that equals large savings.